# Why didn't they use another plan in The Road to El Dorado?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-road-to-el-dorado

At the end of the Dreamworks movie *The Road to El Dorado* (2000) :

> They use a ship full of gold and waste it all in order to stop the Spanish army to attack El Dorado

Why would they do that ? If the goal was :

> to destroy two columns

With all the resources El Dorado have (like giant columns for example), why did they have to use that way less convenient plan? Is there a in-movie explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tulio and Miguel are pressed with time to come up with a plan to stop the quickly approaching Spanish army. They know they need to knock down the 2 main support pillars in the tunnel to close the passageway to El Dorado, but there is no time to rig something up outside of ramming them with the ship that has been made for them. Remember the two support pillars are not in an easily accessible area and surrounded by flowing water, so simply knocking other pillars into them wouldn't have been possible with the limited time.

It was never their intention to lose all the gold on the ship when ramming the pillars, their plan was to simply ram the pillars and escape with the gold.

Simply put: With the limited time and resources this was the best plan they could come up with.